# How to Run Multiple Functions in Python Multiprocess Pool using .starmap_async()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am attempting to run two functions (scatterfunc1, and scatterfunc2) in the same pool using .starmap_async. The first result (result1) runs as expected producing the desired matrix, but result2 isn't populated, and returns an empty matrix. Is there a way to get both results to populate?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    result1 = pool.starmap_async(scatterfunc1, args)
    result2 = pool.starmap_async(scatterfunc2, args)


result1 = np.asarray(result1.get(), dtype = float)
result2 = np.asarray(result2.get(), dtype = float)
```

Comment: I could honestly believe that this is a bug.  That pools aren't designed to have multiple streams running concurrently.  I'm definitely following this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). and it appears you have an indentation error. You also tagged this with `threadpool`, which is not relevant but did not tag the question with the platform you are running on, which is relevant. So please update your question with the *minimal code that we can copy and paste with no  modifications that executes* and *duplicates this error*. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankYellin And I am somewhat skeptical that this *is* a bug -- that's why I need to see a minimal, reproducible example. I wrote a small program that did two `starmap_async` calls like the posted code and then called `get` on the two returned `AsyncResult` instances and had no problems getting the correct results back for each.

Comment: @BooBoo. Thanks.  I missed the indentation problem. Too much staring at the screen that day.  Sorry.

Comment: Was that just a copying problem to this post or is that indentation problem in your actual code?